# How to handle multiple data for a single node in WSO2 EI?

Tags: wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-esb

I am currently trying to create a REST API from a SOAP Endpoint using WSO2 EI.
Source system sends data in JSON format and internally we convert it to xml and send it to the destination system.
The issue we are facing here is when there is multiple data(array) which has to be sent to a single node, we are unable to achieve it. Please let us know which mediator in EI should be used along with an example if possible.

Sample SOAP Message

```html
<fcub:Detbs-Jrnl-Txn-Detail>
                  <fcub:SERIAL_NO>1</fcub:SERIAL_NO>
                  <fcub:DR_CR>D</fcub:DR_CR>
                  <fcub:BRANCH_CODE>001</fcub:BRANCH_CODE>
                  <fcub:CCY>EUR</fcub:CCY>
                  <fcub:AMOUNT>20</fcub:AMOUNT>
                  <fcub:TXN_CODE>TOP</fcub:TXN_CODE>
                  <fcub:LCY_AMOUNT>20</fcub:LCY_AMOUNT>
                  <fcub:ADDL_TEXT>test Mjrnl</fcub:ADDL_TEXT>
                  <fcub:ACCOUNT>001000032027</fcub:ACCOUNT>
</fcub:Detbs-Jrnl-Txn-Detail>
<fcub:Detbs-Jrnl-Txn-Detail>
                  <fcub:SERIAL_NO>2</fcub:SERIAL_NO>
                  <fcub:DR_CR>C</fcub:DR_CR>
                  <fcub:BRANCH_CODE>001</fcub:BRANCH_CODE>
                  <fcub:CCY>EUR</fcub:CCY>
                  <fcub:AMOUNT>20</fcub:AMOUNT>
                  <fcub:TXN_CODE>TOP</fcub:TXN_CODE>
                  <fcub:INSTRUMENT_NO></fcub:INSTRUMENT_NO>
                  <fcub:LCY_AMOUNT>20</fcub:LCY_AMOUNT>
                  <fcub:ADDL_TEXT>test Mjrnl</fcub:ADDL_TEXT>
                  <fcub:ACCOUNT>110000100</fcub:ACCOUNT>
</fcub:Detbs-Jrnl-Txn-Detail>
```

In the above case, for `<fcub:Detbs-Jrnl-Txn-Detail>`, we have two sets of data with serial number 1 and serial number 2.

The corresponding JSON message will be

```html
{
  "CREATEMJRNLBOOK_IOPK_REQ": {
    "FCUBS_HEADER": {
      "SOURCE": "SAP_CONCUR",
      "UBSCOMP": "FCUBS",
      "MSGID": "TEST1234",
      "USERID": "PARAMUSER3",
      "ENTITY": "ENTITY_ID2",
      "BRANCH": "001",
      "SERVICE": "FCUBSDEService",
      "OPERATION": "CreateMjrnlbook"
    },
    "FCUBS_BODY": {
      "Detbs-Jrnl-Txn-Master-Full": {
        "VALUE_DATE": "2021-07-28",
        "BRANCH_CODE": "001",
        "Detbs-Jrnl-Txn-Detail": [
          {
            "SERIAL_NO": 1,
            "DR_CR": "D",
            "BRANCH_CODE": "001",
            "CCY": "EUR",
            "AMOUNT": 20,
            "TXN_CODE": "TOP",
            "INSTRUMENT_NO": 0,
            "LCY_AMOUNT": 20,
            "ADDL_TEXT": "test Mjrnl",
            "ACCOUNT": "001000032027"
          },
          {
            "SERIAL_NO": 2,
            "DR_CR": "C",
            "BRANCH_CODE": "001",
            "CCY": "EUR",
            "AMOUNT": 20,
            "TXN_CODE": "TOP",
            "INSTRUMENT_NO": 0,
            "LCY_AMOUNT": 20,
            "ADDL_TEXT": "test Mjrnl",
            "ACCOUNT": "001000032027"
          }
        ],
        "Devws-Batch-Master": {
          "BALANCING": "Y"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Proxy.xml from EI

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<proxy name="DEService" startOnLoad="true" transports="http https"
    xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <target>
        <inSequence>
            <log description="Logger to Check JSON Message from Proxy" level="full"/>
            <header description="SOAPAction" name="SOAPAction" scope="transport" value=""/>
            <property action="remove" name="REST_URL_POSTFIX" scope="axis2"/>
            <payloadFactory description="Build Request Payload" media-type="xml">
                <format>
                    <soapenv:Envelope
                        xmlns:fcub="http://fcubs.ofss.com/service/FCUBSDEService"
                        xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
                        <soapenv:Header/>
                        <soapenv:Body>
                            <fcub:CREATEMJRNLBOOK_IOPK_REQ>
                                <fcub:FCUBS_HEADER>
                                    <fcub:MODULEID>$1</fcub:MODULEID>
                                    <fcub:USERID>$2</fcub:USERID>
                                    <fcub:ACTION>$3</fcub:ACTION>
                                    <fcub:SOURCE_OPERATION>$4</fcub:SOURCE_OPERATION>
                                    <fcub:MSGID>$5</fcub:MSGID>
                                    <fcub:FUNCTIONID>$6</fcub:FUNCTIONID>
                                    <fcub:MSGSTAT>$7</fcub:MSGSTAT>
                                    <fcub:ENTITY>$8</fcub:ENTITY>
                                    <fcub:UBSCOMP>$9</fcub:UBSCOMP>
                                    <fcub:OPERATION>$10</fcub:OPERATION>
                                    <fcub:BRANCH>$11</fcub:BRANCH>
                                    <fcub:MULTITRIPID>$12</fcub:MULTITRIPID>
                                    <fcub:SNAPSHOTID>$13</fcub:SNAPSHOTID>
                                    <fcub:SERVICE>$14</fcub:SERVICE>
                                    <fcub:SOURCE>$15</fcub:SOURCE>
                                    <fcub:PASSWORD>$16</fcub:PASSWORD>
                                    <fcub:CORRELID>$17</fcub:CORRELID>
                                    <fcub:DESTINATION>$18</fcub:DESTINATION>
                                    <fcub:SOURCE_USERID>$19</fcub:SOURCE_USERID>
                                </fcub:FCUBS_HEADER>
                                <fcub:FCUBS_BODY>
                                    <fcub:Detbs-Jrnl-Txn-Master-Full>
                                        <fcub:VALUE_DATE>$20</fcub:VALUE_DATE>
                                        <fcub:BRANCH_CODE>$21</fcub:BRANCH_CODE>
                                        <fcub:Detbs-Jrnl-Txn-Detail>
                                            <fcub:SERIAL_NO>$22</fcub:SERIAL_NO>
                                            <fcub:DR_CR>$23</fcub:DR_CR>
                                            <fcub:BRANCH_CODE>$24</fcub:BRANCH_CODE>
                                            <fcub:CCY>$25</fcub:CCY>
                                            <fcub:AMOUNT>$26</fcub:AMOUNT>
                                            <fcub:TXN_CODE>$27</fcub:TXN_CODE>
                                            <fcub:LCY_AMOUNT>$28</fcub:LCY_AMOUNT>
                                            <fcub:ADDL_TEXT>$29</fcub:ADDL_TEXT>
                                            <fcub:ACCOUNT>$30</fcub:ACCOUNT>
                                        </fcub:Detbs-Jrnl-Txn-Detail>
                                        <fcub:Devws-Batch-Master>
                                            <fcub:BALANCING>$31</fcub:BALANCING>
                                        </fcub:Devws-Batch-Master>
                                    </fcub:Detbs-Jrnl-Txn-Master-Full>
                                </fcub:FCUBS_BODY>
                            </fcub:CREATEMJRNLBOOK_IOPK_REQ>
                        </soapenv:Body>
                    </soapenv:Envelope>
                </format>
                <args>
                    <arg evaluator="json" expression="$.CREATEMJRNLBOOK_IOPK_REQ.FCUBS_HEADER.MODULEID"/>
                    <arg evaluator="json" expression="$.CREATEMJRNLBOOK_IOPK_REQ.FCUBS_HEADER.USERID"/>
                    <arg evaluator="json" expression="$.CREATEMJRNLBOOK_IOPK_REQ.FCUBS_HEADER.ACTION"/>
                    <arg evaluator="json" expression="$.CREATEMJRNLBOOK_IOPK_REQ.FCUBS_HEADER.SOURCE_OPERATION"/>
                    <arg evaluator="json" expression="$.CREATEMJRNLBOOK_IOPK_REQ.FCUBS_HEADER.MSGID"/>
                    <arg evaluator="json" expression="$.CREATEMJRNLBOOK_IOPK_REQ.FCUBS_HEADER.FUNCTIONID"/>
                    <arg evaluator="json" expression="$.CREATEMJRNLBOOK_IOPK_REQ.FCUBS_HEADER.MSGSTAT"/>
                    <arg evaluator="json" expression="$.CREATEMJRNLBOOK_IOPK_REQ.FCUBS_HEADER.ENTITY"/>
                    <arg evaluator="json" expression="$.CREATEMJRNLBOOK_IOPK_REQ.FCUBS_HEADER.UBSCOMP"/>
                    <arg evaluator="json" expression="$.CREATEMJRNLBOOK_IOPK_REQ.FCUBS_HEADER.OPERATION"/>
                    <arg evaluator="json" expression="$.CREATEMJRNLBOOK_IOPK_REQ.FCUBS_HEADER.BRANCH"/>
                    <arg evaluator="json" expression="$.CREATEMJRNLBOOK_IOPK_REQ.FCUBS_HEADER.MULTITRIPID"/>
                    <arg evaluator="json" expression="$.CREATEMJRNLBOOK_IOPK_REQ.FCUBS_HEADER.SNAPSHOTID"/>
                    <arg evaluator="json" expression="$.CREATEMJRNLBOOK_IOPK_REQ.FCUBS_HEADER.SERVICE"/>
                    <arg evaluator="json" expression="$.CREATEMJRNLBOOK_IOPK_REQ.FCUBS_HEADER.SOURCE"/>
                    <arg evaluator="json" expression="$.CREATEMJRNLBOOK_IOPK_REQ.FCUBS_HEADER.PASSWORD"/>
                    <arg evaluator="json" expression="$.CREATEMJRNLBOOK_IOPK_REQ.FCUBS_HEADER.CORRELID"/>
                    <arg evaluator="json" expression="$.CREATEMJRNLBOOK_IOPK_REQ.FCUBS_HEADER.DESTINATION"/>
                    <arg evaluator="json" expression="$.CREATEMJRNLBOOK_IOPK_REQ.FCUBS_HEADER.SOURCE_USERID"/>
                    <arg evaluator="json" expression="$.CREATEMJRNLBOOK_IOPK_REQ.FCUBS_BODY.Detbs-Jrnl-Txn-Master-Full.VALUE_DATE"/>
                    <arg evaluator="json" expression="$.CREATEMJRNLBOOK_IOPK_REQ.FCUBS_BODY.Detbs-Jrnl-Txn-Master-Full.BRANCH_CODE"/>
                    <arg evaluator="json" expression="$.CREATEMJRNLBOOK_IOPK_REQ.FCUBS_BODY.Detbs-Jrnl-Txn-Master-Full.Detbs-Jrnl-Txn-Detail.SERIAL_NO"/>
                    <arg evaluator="json" expression="$.CREATEMJRNLBOOK_IOPK_REQ.FCUBS_BODY.Detbs-Jrnl-Txn-Master-Full.Detbs-Jrnl-Txn-Detail.DR_CR"/>
                    <arg evaluator="json" expression="$.CREATEMJRNLBOOK_IOPK_REQ.FCUBS_BODY.Detbs-Jrnl-Txn-Master-Full.Detbs-Jrnl-Txn-Detail.BRANCH_CODE"/>
                    <arg evaluator="json" expression="$.CREATEMJRNLBOOK_IOPK_REQ.FCUBS_BODY.Detbs-Jrnl-Txn-Master-Full.Detbs-Jrnl-Txn-Detail.CCY"/>
                    <arg evaluator="json" expression="$.CREATEMJRNLBOOK_IOPK_REQ.FCUBS_BODY.Detbs-Jrnl-Txn-Master-Full.Detbs-Jrnl-Txn-Detail.AMOUNT"/>
                    <arg evaluator="json" expression="$.CREATEMJRNLBOOK_IOPK_REQ.FCUBS_BODY.Detbs-Jrnl-Txn-Master-Full.Detbs-Jrnl-Txn-Detail.TXN_CODE"/>
                    <arg evaluator="json" expression="$.CREATEMJRNLBOOK_IOPK_REQ.FCUBS_BODY.Detbs-Jrnl-Txn-Master-Full.Detbs-Jrnl-Txn-Detail.LCY_AMOUNT"/>
                    <arg evaluator="json" expression="$.CREATEMJRNLBOOK_IOPK_REQ.FCUBS_BODY.Detbs-Jrnl-Txn-Master-Full.Detbs-Jrnl-Txn-Detail.ADDL_TEXT"/>
                    <arg evaluator="json" expression="$.CREATEMJRNLBOOK_IOPK_REQ.FCUBS_BODY.Detbs-Jrnl-Txn-Master-Full.Detbs-Jrnl-Txn-Detail.ACCOUNT"/>
                    <arg evaluator="json" expression="$.CREATEMJRNLBOOK_IOPK_REQ.FCUBS_BODY.Detbs-Jrnl-Txn-Master-Full.Devws-Batch-Master.BALANCING"/>
                </args>
            </payloadFactory>
            <property description="messageProperty" name="messageType" scope="axis2" type="STRING" value="application/soap+xml"/>
            <property description="ContentType" name="ContentType" scope="axis2" type="STRING" value="text/xml"/>
            <log description="Logger to check XML Message" level="full"/>
            <send>
                <endpoint key="FCUBSDEService_ADDRESS_EP"/>
            </send>
        </inSequence>
        <outSequence>
            <property description="Convert XML to Payload" name="messageType" scope="axis2" type="STRING" value="application/json"/>
            <log description="Logger to Check Payload Response" level="full"/>
            <send/>
        </outSequence>
        <faultSequence/>
    </target>
</proxy>
```

Please let us know how to achieve this using EI.
Thanks
Tandon

Answer (score 0):

For that You should use `Iterate mediator`, described in [this documentation](https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI660/Iterate+Mediator+). Look at this [XPath example](https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI660/Iterate+Mediator#c4c1163c6eed4284997cbea6c89cec72).
But described by you JSON example, is not valid, because it should contain Array as `Detbs-Jrnl-Txn-Detail`. Its would be easier if i can see more msg context.

Comment: Thanks tmoasz. I have gone through the documentation but it is a in a very simple form. I have added the proxy-service xml above and am not sure where to add the iterate mediator. Request your help please!

Comment: OK, now its a bit more clear. First, your JSON is not valid. It has missing coma, and after fixing this you will have duplicate key `Detbs-Jrnl-Txn-Detail`, not an Array. So it looks more like tranformation problem, not sendind multiple data - if yes, you can look on `ForEach Mediator` or maybe `XSLT Mediator`

Comment: Hi, Sorry, I have updated the json request so that it will be an array. The proxy.xml from EI has also been updated to access these. Please let me know if Iterate or forEach Mediator should be used. Kindly provide an example as well.

Comment: @TandonG i think `ForEach Mediator` should be ok, look for this example: https://medium.com/@Manuri/wso2-esb-foreach-mediator-example-87f041e2a912

Comment: I tried with the ForEach Mediator and im getting the below error in Postman `{
    "Envelope": {
        "Body": {
            "Fault": {
                "faultcode": "ns0:Client",
                "faultstring": "Cannot find dispatch method for {}jsonObject"
            }
        }
    }
}`   I believe Im using the wrong expression in foreach. Please correct me if I am wrong. I am currently using `<foreach expression="//fcub:Detbs-Jrnl-Txn-Detail" xmlns:fcub="http://fcubs.ofss.com/service/FCUBSDEService">
<sequence> before the <payloadFactory >`